# Jest testing a class that uses sqlite3; jest cannot find sqlite3/package.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, package.json, node-sqlite3

I am trying to write unit tests of a class which utilizes sqlite3, using TypeScript.

The class itself can correctly utilize sqlite3, but when I try to test the functions which use sqlite3, I get the following error message:

```
Test suite failed to run

    package.json does not exist at C:\...\node_modules\sqlite3\package.json
```

When I click that link, however, it opens up the package.json file. So it does, actually, exist.

A simplified version of the class under test is as follows:

```js
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

export class DataManager {
  database_path: string;
  gamertags: { [key: string]: any };
  api: object;

  constructor() {
    //Prepare database
    this.database_path = path.join(__dirname, "..", "data", "DBName.db");
  }

  public mainloop = async () => {
    //Setup database
    this.setup_db(this.database_path);
  };

  setup_db = async (db_path: string) => {
    //Create data directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "data"))) {
      fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "data"));
    }

    //Get read/write connection to database
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(db_path);

    //Serialize context to make sure tables are created in order
    db.serialize(() => {
      //Create table_1
      db.run(`sql_query...`);

      //Create table_2
      db.run(`sql_query...`);
    });
  };
}
```

And my unit tests:

```js
import { DataManager } from "../../core/dataManager";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import fs from "fs";
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";

jest.mock("fs");
jest.mock("sqlite3");

let manager: DataManager;
const fake_database_path: string = "fake/database/path";

describe("datamanager.setup_db", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    manager = new DataManager();
    manager.database_path = fake_database_path;
  });

  it("should create a new database file if one does not exist", async () => {
    //Arrange
    mocked(fs).existsSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue = false as any;
    mocked(sqlite3).Database = jest.fn() as any;

    //Act
    await manager.setup_db(fake_database_path);
  });
});
```

I'm just not sure what on earth is preventing sqlite3 from finding its own `package.json`. None of my other dependencies seem to cause a fuss, yet sqlite3 does.

Comment: I've noticed that you mock 'existsSync' to always return false. Can it be the issue for 'sqlite3'? Have you tried running the test without mocking 'existsSync'?

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was, thank you! I guess mocking out filesystem calls can ruin imports for some packages. I wonder if there's still a way to control calls to fs...

Comment: can you write a solution for us? @AnastasiiaSolop

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamer you should simply find a way of testing it without mocking fs.existsSync or if it the only way, then to mock it in only a very specific case that is preventing you from removing the mock.
In general mocking 'fs' is not the best idea, since many libraries depend on it and this may lead to unexpected errors in the test.